# Is my approach to implement Producer-Consumer problem correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have implemented producer problem using wait/notify combination. Could someone please let me know if my understanding on producer consumer problem is correct or not and if my implementation is correct/optimized?

Now i'm thinking how to implement the same problem using `ExecutorService` and `CountDownLatch`, `ReentrantLock`, `CyclicBarrier`? Is there any way to do it? Meanwhile I will try to see if I can implement the problem solution using the latch.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProducerConsumerProblem {

    private Object syncher = new Object();
    private volatile ArrayList<Integer> sharedBuffer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProducerConsumerProblem object = new ProducerConsumerProblem();

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            object.produceData();
        },"Producer");
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            object.consumeData();
        },"Consumer");
        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();
    }

    public void produceData() {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        while(true) {
            synchronized (syncher) {
                if(sharedBuffer.size() == 1) {
                    try {
                        //System.out.println("Producer waiting...");
                        syncher.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Integer producedElem = randomNumber.nextInt(10);
                System.out.println("+++ Produced: "+producedElem);
                sharedBuffer.add(producedElem);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                syncher.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public void consumeData() {
        while(true) {
            synchronized (syncher) {
                while(sharedBuffer.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        //System.out.println("Consumer waiting...");
                        syncher.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Integer consumedElem = sharedBuffer.stream().findAny().orElseThrow(()-> new EmptyStackException());
                System.out.println("--- Consumed: "+consumedElem);
                sharedBuffer.remove(consumedElem);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                syncher.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use standard implementation of BlockingQueue?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: I was trying to implement firstly using wait/notify then will proceed implementing via BlockingQueue, CountDownLatch, ReentrantLock, CyclicBarrier

Comment: You should post that on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: Is the answered solution for producer consumer problem using BlockingQueue fine?

Comment: @ManishAdhikari yes it is. The only remark: ".intValue()" is redundant.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: ohh yeah, thanks!
My bad! forgot to take care of autoboxing/ unboxing

Comment: @ManishAdhikari on the other hand, your variant with ".intValue()"  executes faster - it writes the number image directly to StringBuilder, while my variant creates an intermediate string with  number image and only then writes it to StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class ProducerConsumerProblemUsingBlockingQueue {

    BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProducerConsumerProblemUsingBlockingQueue object = new ProducerConsumerProblemUsingBlockingQueue();

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            object.produceData(object.blockingQueue);
        },"Producer");
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(() -> {
            object.consumeData(object.blockingQueue);
        },"Consumer");
        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();
    }

    private void consumeData(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Consumed: "+blockingQueue.take().intValue());
                Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void produceData(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue) {
        Random randomObject = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                int randomNumber = randomObject.nextInt(100);
                System.out.println("Produced: "+randomNumber);
                blockingQueue.put(randomNumber);
                Thread.sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```